# Reason for the method of factorization of cyclic expressions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, intuition, factoring

For example, I am given that factorize:

> $$a^2b+a^2c+ab^2+2abc+ac^2+b^2c+bc^2$$

So by the traditional method, we take the powers of $a$
$$=a^2(b+c)+a(b+c)^2+bc(b+c)$$
$$=(b+c)(a^2+ab+ac+bc)$$
Now the powers of $b$:
$$=(b+c)(b(a+c)+a(a+c))$$
$$=(b+c)(a+c)(a+b)$$
Which gives a neat factorization. 
But my question is: **Why does this method work at all?** Any intuition? Any proof?

Comment: This does not always work, since just look at:
$$
a^3-a (3bc)+b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)
$$

Comment: It's $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$, which is invariant under any permutation of the variables.

Comment: @ÁkosSomogyi. Okay, but it does work for some. So what is the explanation for those?

Comment: Why do you expect a proof on solving an algebric expression?

Comment: I am not exactly expecting a proof, but an intuition, or an explanation. And common, there has to be a proof of that? Like for quadratic expressions, there **is** a rigorous explanation for factoring them. @tatan.